# How to filter the sub menu from the json data and bind to html in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a JSON data, which consists of ID and parentID,
Now i need to bind the values in HTML with ID and its parentID.
Can anyone help me how to do this.

JSON data:

```
(19) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {ID: 1, Text: "Home / Dashboard", Description: "Home / Dashboard", ParentMenuId: 0, isChecked: true}
1: {ID: 2, Text: "User Management", Description: "User Management", ParentMenuId: 0}
2: {ID: 3, Text: "Basic Users", Description: "Basic Users", ParentMenuId: 2}
3: {ID: 4, Text: "Admin Users", Description: "Admin Users", ParentMenuId: 2}
4: {ID: 5, Text: "Dicom", Description: "Dicom", ParentMenuId: 0}
5: {ID: 6, Text: "EMR", Description: "EMR", ParentMenuId: 0}
6: {ID: 7, Text: "Case Management", Description: "Case Management", ParentMenuId: 0}
7: {ID: 8, Text: "System Settings", Description: "System Settings", ParentMenuId: 0}
8: {ID: 9, Text: "Deployment", Description: "Deployment", ParentMenuId: 0}
9: {ID: 10, Text: "Environment", Description: "Environment", ParentMenuId: 0}
10: {ID: 12, Text: "Lookup Master", Description: "Lookup Master", ParentMenuId: 8}
11: {ID: 13, Text: "User Authorization", Description: "User Authorization", ParentMenuId: 8}
12: {ID: 14, Text: "Report", Description: "Report", ParentMenuId: 0, isChecked: true}
13: {ID: 15, Text: "Admin Authorization", Description: "Admin Authorization", ParentMenuId: 8}
14: {ID: 16, Text: "Multilingual Master", Description: "Multilingual Master", ParentMenuId: 8}
15: {ID: 17, Text: "Cache Server", Description: "Cache Server", ParentMenuId: 10, isChecked: true}
16: {ID: 18, Text: "Cache Details", Description: "Cache Details", ParentMenuId: 10, isChecked: true}
17: {ID: 19, Text: "Data Storage", Description: "Data Storage", ParentMenuId: 10}
18: {ID: 20, Text: "Viewers", Description: "Viewers", ParentMenuId: 10}
length: 19
: Array(0)
```

TS:

```
getMenu() {
    this._Service.getMenu()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.userMenu = res.Body.Data
      })
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <div>
      <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
        <ul class="metismenu" id="menu">
          <li class="m--5" *ngFor="let menu of userMenu">
            <a class="nav-link">
              <input type="checkbox" [checked]="menu.isChecked" (click)="selectedMenu($event.target.checked, menu.ID)">
              <span class="nav-text p-l10">{{menu.Text}}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

1. SO, here i want Parent to be at TOP and Child must be just below the parent with a tab space.
2. When child is checked, automatically the parent should also be checked.

My requirement is:

[image]

But i am getting in this way:

[image]

[Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzhuxs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Can you please share code of whatever you have tried so far. Creating a minimal reproduction on stackblitz will also help us to help you.

Comment: i have tried to create same way but it is not giving output

Comment: il atleast post al my codes

Comment: @SachinGupta Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzhuxs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to do it is to filter it based on menu id and have nest `ul->li`

```
<ul class="metismenu" id="menu">
    <li class="m--5" *ngFor="let menu of userMenu">
        <a class="nav-link">
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="menu.isChecked" (click)="selectedMenu($event.target.checked, menu.ID)">
            <span class="nav-text p-l10">{{menu.Text}}
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let submenu of subUserMenu(menu.ID)">
                    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="submenu.isChecked" (click)="selectedMenu($event.target.checked, submenu.ID)">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> {{submenu.Text}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            </span>  
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

subUserMenu(menuId){
    return  this.userMenu.filter(x=>x.ParentMenuId===menuId);
}
```

**update:**

added a property to get the parent user menus. So you will be looping through that.

```
get parentUserMenu(){
    return this.userMenu.filter(x=>x.ParentMenuId===0);
}

<ul class="metismenu" id="menu">
    <li class="m--5" *ngFor="let menu of parentUserMenu">
        <a class="nav-link">
            ...
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blwojt

**update 2:**

```
checkParent(id){
    const item = this.userMenu.find(x=>x.ID == id);
    if(item.ParentMenuId !== 0){
        let parent = this.userMenu.find(x=>x.ID===item.ParentMenuId)
        if(parent.isChecked === undefined || parent.isChecked===false){
            parent.isChecked = true;
            this.selectedMenuIds.push(parent.ID);
        }
    }
}

unCheckParent(id){
    const item = this.userMenu.find(x=>x.ID == id);
    if(item.ParentMenuId !== 0){
        var siblings = this.userMenu.filter(x=>x.ParentMenuId === item.ParentMenuId);
        if(siblings.filter(x=>x.isChecked===true).length === 0){
            let parent = this.userMenu.find(x=>x.ID == item.ParentMenuId);
            parent.isChecked = false;
            this.selectedMenuIds.splice(this.selectedMenuIds.indexOf(parent.ID), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

so when a checkbox is checked, you find the parent and make it checked if its not already checked, and you do the same when the last child is unchecked.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxpd5y

**update 3:** 
Basically you find all the child and check/uncheck them all and push/splice them

```
//'check all child'
let childs = this.userMenu.filter(x=>x.ParentMenuId === item.ID);
childs.forEach(x=>{
    x.isChecked = true;
    this.selectedMenuIds.push(x.ID);
});

//uncheck all child
let childs = this.userMenu.filter(x=>x.ParentMenuId === item.ID);
childs.forEach(x=>{
    x.isChecked = false;
    this.selectedMenuIds.splice(this.selectedMenuIds.indexOf(x.ID), 1);
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ziyexq

Comment: Thanks for the response but the sub menus are repeating but that shouldnt happen

Comment: Thank you, 1 condition is fine, how can i get the parent also checked when child is checked?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me

Comment: one more pls, if i check parent, then all childs should be checked